# SQL Change a parameters value of a list of strings /varchar to a list of integers

Tags: sql, string, casting, integer

How do I change my parameters value made from a case statement of:

```
Set @CostType=Case When @ShowLabor ='Y'and @ShowEquipment ='Y' then ('1,3,5,7,8')
                when @ShowLabor ='Y'and @ShowEquipment ='N' then ('3,5')
                when @ShowLabor ='N'and @ShowEquipment ='Y' then ('1,7,8')
                else ('1,3,5,7,8') end
```

to a list of integers [EX:(1,3,5,7,8)] in order to be part of this `IN` statement:

```
Where JCCD.CostType in (@CostType)
```

I also tried doing this as a column in a temp table as seen below, let me know if that is easier to convert from:

```
Declare @TempTable table (CostType int)
Set NOCOUNT ON;
Insert into @TempTable values 
(Case When @ShowLabor ='Y'and @ShowEquipment ='Y' then ('1,3,5,7,8')
      when @ShowLabor ='Y'and @ShowEquipment ='N' then ('3,5')
      when @ShowLabor ='N'and @ShowEquipment ='Y' then ('1,7,8')
      else   ('1,3,5,7,8') end )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommending normalizing your `TempTable`, something like this:

```
ShowLabor | ShowEquipment | CostType
1         | 1             | 1
1         | 1             | 3
1         | 1             | 5
1         | 1             | 7
1         | 1             | 8
1         | 0             | 3
1         | 0             | 5
0         | 1             | 1
0         | 1             | 7
0         | 1             | 8
```

With this refactor, you can write a proper query along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM JCCD
WHERE CostType IN (SELECT CostType FROM TempTable
                   WHERE ShowLabor = 1 AND ShowEquipment = 1);
```

In general storing CSV data into a single column/row in a database is not good practice.  It would be much better to have each cost type value on a separate row, as shown above.

Comment: Thanks so much, works perfect, I had a tough time with this until I used this.